# ReactJs TypeError: Cannot read property 'clicked' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am getting this error while I use `state.clicked` statement inside if-else condition.
Below is my code,

**Hamburger.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Hamburger = ({ state }) => {
  let menu = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (state.clicked === false) {
      //close our menu
      menu.style.display = "none";
    } else if (
      state.clicked === true ||
      (state.clicked === true && state.initial === null)
    ) {
      // open our menu
      menu.style.display = "block";
    }
  });

  return (
    <div ref={(el) => (menu = el)} className="hamburger-menu">
      <div className="menu-secondary-background-color"></div>
      <div className="menu-layer">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="wrapper">
            <div className="menu-links">
              <nav>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <Link to="/opportunities">Opportunities</Link>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <Link to="/opportunities">Work</Link>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <Link to="/opportunities">Contact</Link>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </nav>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Hamburger;
```

**Header.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Hamburger from "./Hamburger";

const Header = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    initial: false,
    clicked: null,
    menuName: "Menu",
  });

  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);

  const handleMenu = () => {
    disableMenu();
    if (state.initial === false) {
      setState({
        inital: null,
        clicked: true,
        menuName: "Close",
      });
    } else if (state.clicked === true) {
      setState({
        clicked: !state.clicked,
        menuName: "Menu",
      });
    } else if (state.clicked === false) {
      setState({
        clicked: !state.clicked,
        menuName: "Close",
      });
    }
  };

  // Determine if our menu button should be disabled
  const disableMenu = () => {
    setDisabled(!disabled);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setDisabled(false);
    }, 1200);
  };

  return (
    <header>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="wrapper">
          <div className="inner-header">
            <div className="logo">
              <Link to="/">Adarsh Goldar</Link>
            </div>
            <div className="menu">
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
              <Link to="/">About</Link>
              <button disabled={disabled} onClick={handleMenu}>
                Menu
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Hamburger />
    </header>
  );
};
export default Header;
```

Comment: if the answer was helpful then make it as accepted

Comment: Pass state as prop in Hamburger component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes because you have not passed state as a prop to do that change your code as below
in header.js

```
<Hamburger state={state}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

well you need to pass state props to Your component:

```
<Hamburger state={state}/>
```

and for Hamburger you dont need to use `useEffect` and ref to  update the style because when state props change the component will re render and every code will run again.
here how to do it with jsx style:

```
const Hamburger = ({ state }) => { 
  return (
    <div style={{display:state.clicked?"block":"none"}} className="hamburger-menu">
      <div className="menu-secondary-background-color"></div>
      <div className="menu-layer">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="wrapper">
            <div className="menu-links">
              <nav>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <Link to="/opportunities">Opportunities</Link>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <Link to="/opportunities">Work</Link>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <Link to="/opportunities">Contact</Link>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </nav>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Hamburger;
```

and you can wrap `Hamburger` component in `React.memo` to prevent unnecessary re render so it will re render only when state props change : `export default` React.memo(Hamburger)`